# Title bar and decorations missing: Unity desktop

Tags: unity

```
uname -a:
Linux splitter 2.6.38-8-server #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:49:04 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

All of the windows on my desktop are missing a title bar and the decorations to maximize/minimize and close the window. I can reposition a window only by holding down the left ALT key while doing a left mouse click and drag. I can maximize/minimize a window only by using ctl-alt-keypad-5. I can close a window only by using a quit menu entry or by using the desktop toolbar on the left side.

I suspect that I accidentally hit some sort of weird key combination and set a sticky preference of some sort, but I can't for the life of me find out where to reset it. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Open CompizConfig Settings Manager and on the effects tab make sure you have the 'Window Decoration' tickbox checked like below;

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Had to install the pkg, but this might have been the problem.