# How do I make the Panel and Window Decorations appear on a second monitor?

Tags: unity, compiz, nvidia, multiple-monitors

64-bit 11.04 installed with the proprietary NVIDIA (current) enabled, all updates applied as of today.

**I'm having trouble setting up my second monitor. I have no panel or window decorations on the second monitor. How do I make them appear?**

I'm using the current NVIDIA proprietary driver with their settings-manager. The second screen configured as a separate X screen, no Twinview.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5998/window-decorations-disappeared) recommended running `metacity --replace`, that brought the window decorations back but killed desktop effects, the panel on my primary monitor, as well as my launcher bar.

I tried to grab a screenshot of the second screen, but the image taken was of the primary screen, even though I manually selected a portion on the second monitor...strange.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40847/title-bar-and-decorations-missing-unity-desktop) recommends making sure 'Window Decoration' is checked in CompizConfig Settings Manager, it is, and has been by default since install.

The top answer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9886/how-does-unity-work-in-multi-monitor-configurations) has it set up with Twinview. That doesn't work for me, since fullscreen Flash video with Twinview reverts back to my primary monitor. The second is a HDTV that I will only use for fullscreen video playback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These bugs might be relevant: [#779867](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/779867), [#711456](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/711456), [#779124](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/779124)

Alternatives are to try Twinview Cloning or Ubuntu Classic.

There are [workarounds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43755/dual-monitor-youtube-full-screen-help) for fullscreen flash depending on the source.

Comment: Thanks, I like Unity but I'll try Classic when I want to watch video on the second (large) screen. Cloning won't work for me as both screens are near each other and that would be distracting.